# Google Maps API Javascript & Following Markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, focus, marker

I'm currently using javascript Google Maps API to place markers on the map and move the markers around the map to different coordinates. I am able to place a marker on the map and have it updated so that the marker moves around the map but if the marker moves farther than the edge of the map how can I refocus the map so that the marker stays in the center of the map without redrawing the whole map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `Map.getBounds()` to get the bounds of the map and `LatLngBounds.contains(latLng:LatLng)` to check if the point is outside of the map then can set the centre of the map with `Map.setCenter(latlng:LatLng)`, just set the LatLng as the same as the marker.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference